# cannot create project using android studio

Tags: java, android-studio, android-sdk-2.3

I'm getting the following error when creating a project in android studio:

```
failed to parse SDK!  The Android SDK may be missing the directory
```

and many other problems related to a http proxy.

I've reinstalled the android studio.

Answer (score 0):

You have to select the Android SDK when creating Android project for the first time. Look into this [tutorial](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/Create+a+New+Android+Project) (step 2).

Comment: Now i had reinstalled the android studio but then to im facing problems like ** Unknown host 'repo1.maven.org'.

Please ensure the host name is correct. If you are behind an HTTP proxy, please configure the proxy settings either in Android Studio or Gradle.** what should i do next ?.